# How to design a layout In Android that is suitable for portrait/landscape mode?

Tags: android

I've designed a layout ideally for portrait mode. However, when I switch the layout to landscape mode, the layout crashes. How can this be fixed?

Comment: There are many reasons this could happen. When you rotate the phone android recreates the activity which is likely where your crash is. If you want help with your issue you will need to provide your error messages from logcat and some code of where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to your `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

or handle the change in orientation in code because the change in orientation recreates the activity again.

Comment: Okay I Pasted The Code In My Activity And Still The Same Problem

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml and the Activity code, so we can help you